# Can I make a style for last level in multilevel list with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a large multilevel list like this:

```css
li
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>level1 item</li>
    <li>level1 item
      <ul>
        <li>level2 item</li>
        <li>level2 item
          <ul>
            <li>level3 item</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>level1 item
      <ul>
        <li>level2 item</li>
        <li>level2 item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I need to make a special style for items on the last level only, i.e. if item hasn't any subitems it must have a special style. I could use classes but the problem is that this list is very large and it's not mine so I can't somehow modify the list itself, I can only write the css for it (or write js code, but I don't want to do it)

Comment: ul ul ul li{....} try this. can you make style for last list

Comment: Which `li`s should be affected?

Comment: In my example lists with text "level3 item" and the last 2 items with text "level2 items"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if element has any child, if not apply css

```
$('li').each(function(){
{
    If(!$(this).children().length)
    {
        $(this).addClass("className");
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't want to use js but as I can't see other ways to solve this problem, maybe I will use this code. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I forgot that the code must check only if li tag has ul tag children. I made it myself in my code, but I think it should be added in the answer (just add 'ul' argument to the children() function)

Comment: li should have ul tag child? In that case adding 'ul' to children() function will give wrong result.

Comment: Why? If I put some other tags in the item's text (e.g. if I wrap text between <li> and <ul> in <a> tag) this function won't return 0 so the code will work as if there are subitems in this item and this is a wrong result. But if I filter children I'm looking for and will count only <ul> children, it will work properly. At least it works as I wanted

Answer (score -2):

```
ul>li:last-of-type
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: It's used to set the style for last item, but I need to make style for all items that haven't subitems

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.